# Couldn't find Zone without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

just trying the link_to image_tag helper, and I can't get it to work.

Can someone please tell me whats wrong?

**Controller**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @categories = Category.all
    @zone = Zone.find(params[:id])
    @zones = Zone.all
    @photos = Photo.landing
  end

end
```

**View**

```
    <% @zones.limit(8).each do |zone| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag "category-box_#{zone.id}.jpg", zone(zone.id) %>
    <% end %>
```

**Update**

I found the Id problem came from the controller. Now the error is:

**undefined method `symbolize_keys' for 1:Fixnum**

Thanks!

Comment: Try `link_to image_tag("category-box_#{zone.id}.jpg"), zone_path(zone.id)`

Comment: Try this `<%= link_to image_tag("category-box_#{zone.id}.jpg") , zone_path(zone.id) %>` instead `zone(zone.id)`

Comment: Hello, the correct path is spots_by_zone_path(zone.id), so I did 

<%= link_to image_tag "category-box_#{zone.id}.jpg", spots_by_zone_path(zone.id) %>, but I get undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "/spots/zonas/1":String

Comment: @MirkoAkkov I found out it's the image_tag causing it error. How can I use a different way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your image_tag in brackets. Your code should look something like this:

```
<% @zones.limit(8).each do |zone| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag("category-box_#{zone.id}.jpg"), spots_by_zone_path(zone.id) %>
<% end %>
```

OR

You can simply use [`block form of link_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

```
<% @zones.limit(8).each do |zone| %>
    <%= link_to spots_by_zone_path(zone.id) do %>
      <%= image_tag "category-box_#{zone.id}.jpg" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Gibson When you don't use brackets rails was taking path helper as argument to image_tag and hence causing error